# Excel cannot cut / paste a row when one column is hidden and another is filtered

Tags: excel

When attempting to cut a row and insert it futher down, Excel disallows with message: "The command you chose cannot be peformed with multiple selections".

If I unhide column-D or set the filter on column-F to show all then there is no problem.

This is a simplified example but my real world sheet has several separated hidden columns and 2 filters so it's non-trivial to keep switching things on and off just to move some rows.

Any ideas on a workaround would be appreciated.

Image1 is the sheet before hide and filter and Image2 is the sheet after hide and filter.

[Image1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DsLi3.png) | [Image2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/W2AMV.png)

Answer (score 0):

After more research it appears that this constraint is by design in Excel, i.e. you cannot cut/paste rows from a region which has both hidden columns AND autofiltered columns. For some reason Excel sees the region as having multiple selections, (presumably bounded by the hidden columns), even though it is a single contiguous range.

My solution was to write some VBA which unhides the columns, does the cut/paste then re-hides the columns. This method was chosen rather than clearing/setting the filters as autofilter changes cause the formulas to be flagged as "dirty" and therefore in need of recalculation.